# jQuery: .animate() not working with scrollLeft anymore

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

This is a curious case. I've simply forked an old example by Remy Sharp ( jQuery infinite carousel ) but this time the code simply doesn't work. The only difference in my code is that I need to have a fixed number of items without duplicating the last and first ones.

I think this is somehow related to the CSS code but I can't find a solution. You can find my demo below.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/JlkHe)

Thanks in advance if you can point me in the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use left instead of scrollLeft in the animate.

```
animate({
 left: left
}, 500);
```

Comment: i gived a solution based on your script.

Comment: I saw it. Heck, my fault! :-D